# Assigning a pointer inside a function to an argument and setting pointers to Null inside a function is OK

Tags: c, pointers

**Problem Description**

I'm learning pointers. I managed to write a sample code. But I don't know why it's working correctly. Basically, I'm trying to fill an array inside a function `fillArray`. Since I  need to modify the pointer rather than the object that the pointer is pointing to, I pass a double pointer `**ppArray`. That's like passing a reference to a pointer in `C++`. I use `realloc`to increase the array size every time I want to add a new element.

I get lost the moment I set `pArray to NULL`. How come `*ppArray` hold all the values of `pArray` even after we set `pArray` to NULL. And how come `free(pArray)` causes `double free detected in tcache 2`. I'm setting pArray to NULL!!!. I'm really confused!

---

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

void fillArray(int **ppArray, int *pArraySize){
    int *pArray = NULL;
    int *pTmp;
    int arraySize = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pTmp = realloc(pArray,(arraySize+1) * sizeof(int));
        pArray = pTmp;
        pArray[arraySize] = i;
        arraySize += 1;
    }
    *ppArray = pArray;
    *pArraySize = arraySize;
    //free(pArray) is a no no!! Of course it is a no no. why free the memory while we still need it later it. We can free it once we are done with it
    pArray = NULL;
}

int main() {
    int *pIntegerArray;
    int arraySize;
    fillArray(&pIntegerArray,&arraySize);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf(" %u", pIntegerArray[i]);
    } 
    free(pIntegerArray);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Visual representation**

for the visual reprentation I used the following website [C Tutor - Visualize C code execution to learn C online](http://pythontutor.com/c.html)

[image]

The `free` function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. So all pointers will be pointing to **Sh*t** as illustrated in the below image, in case we free the pointer in  `free(pArray) is a no no!!`. We will be freeing the same **poop** twice if we call `free(pIntegerArray);` in the main function. On top of that we wont be able to get the values of the array since we lost the pointer to the address of the first element of the array.

[image]

Comment: `*ppArray` is a  `pArray`. Once you indirect through `ppArray`, you can access everything `pArray` points to.

Comment: `pArray ` is a local pointer, since you are exiting from the function on the next line, `pArray = NULL;` doesn't make any sense. The point of using a temporary pointer to get the result of `realloc` (don't use it on C++)  is to check if it was set succesfully without introducing a memory leak, always check the result of (m,c,re)alloc.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Why can't I free(pArray)? ooo, is it because it's not allocated dynamically?

Comment: Things would be less confusing if you didn't use the same name `pArray` in both `main()` and `fillArray()`.

Comment: You can't free `pArray` in `fillArray` because it's the array that you're returning to `main()`. If you free it there, `main()` can't print the contents.

Comment: You never assign anything to `pIntegerArray`, it will be `NULL` (maybe, it's UB I think) - so `realloc` has nothing to work with. Did you check the return value of `realloc`? `pArray` is also initialized to NULL. Check your program in a debugger.

Comment: _ooo, is it because it's not allocated dynamically?_  yes it is, but `realloc` (unlike `new`)  can return `NULL`,  in such case you can not access/dereference the pointer.

Comment: In your latest iteration, pArray is undefined in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Aliased_pointers), i.e. multiple pointers which refer to the same memory location. The pointers `*pTmp`, `*pArray`, `*ppArray` and `*pIntegerArray` all refer to the same location in memory. Setting one of these pointers to `NULL` does not change the memory it points to, and hence, it can still be accessed using the other pointers. Calling `free` with any of these pointers *does* change the underlying memory, so trying to free the same allocated memory again using a pointer of a different name results in a "double free".

Another way of looking at it: code like`pArray = pTmp;` copies the pointer (i.e. memory *location*) only; it does not copy the underlying data.

On a side note, `stdlib.h` needs to be included for `realloc`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: Hey Yun. Yes you are righ. i'm trying to draw it to understand what is happeing

Comment: @HaniDaher Even worse, the now invalid pointers are invalid to even copy or print.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica THIS THING IS BEAUTITUL and SCARY. realy scary. Thanks a lot for your comment. More information for me. And of course more knowledge on the beauty of pointers

Comment: @HaniDaher-ReinstateMonica IIRC, copying invalid pointers is UB, yet usually a benign UB.  Moral of the story, avoid lots of copies of a pointer.